# format as link to email address, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, hyperlink

The  `<%= @post.source_account %>`    is an email address. I want this to display as a link that says "Email Me" and when click it will open the users mail client

```
 <% if @post.source_account.present? %>
          <h4>Email Seller: <small> <%= @post.source_account %><br></h4>
          <% end %>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`mail_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/mail_to), which creates a mailto link tag to the specified email address:

```
<%= mail_to @post.source_account, "Email Me" %>
```

Comment: ok this works but addresses the email to only the specific domain in quotes. how can I link to the email address that is generated by the @post.source_account?

Comment: I think, you used my comment. I removed my comment, please see if it serves you what you needed.